# How to save an excel document?

Tags: c#, excel

I have been trying to save an open excel workbook and have not been able to.I am using Visual Studio to write a program in c#. I have a windows Userform which when launches, open an excel document in a webBrowser within the form. On that userform, I created a Save button as I would like to save the changes made to the excel.

My code to open excel in webbrowser is:

```
private void Excelform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //  Application.DoEvents();

    if (File.Exists(m_ExcelFileName))
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(m_ExcelFileName, false);
    }
}
```

This works fine. 
HOWEVER when I try to save the changes to the file I either get an error (File in or OR Operation not Executed). Tried webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog(); but this requires user interaction. All I want is when the user click on the save_btn the file saves.

SO can anyone help be figure out how to save the changes made to an excel file that is currently open in a webBrowser on a userform?

Right now this is all I have:

```
private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        webBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Not updated
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
 }
```

HELP PLEASE :(

Comment: Is the Excel file on a local/shared drive?

Comment: No, its saved on the user's PC in Document folder